# rotation matrix for icosahedral 5 fold symmetry axis

Tags: geometry, rotations

I am not formally trained in math so I apologise in advance for asking a what may be a trivial question. I am trying to find a set of rotation matrices that would go through centers of the of 5-folds of a unit icosahedron. I am aware that an icosahedron can be defined using 60 rotation matrices, however an icosahedron has 12 5-folds which means that there are 48 redundant matrices from the 60. Could you help me understand if it is possible to derive/describe these matrices?

Comment: Take a look at the first part (only !) of this text : https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1057.pdf. You will see in particular formulas (10) and (11) for generating matrices, where  $\phi:=\tfrac12(1+\sqrt{5})$ (golden ratio whose presence isn't surprizing for an icosahedron), taking into account formula (9). Other matrix representation can be puzzling : their presence is explained by (Weyl's) formula (7) which "forecasts" the different possible dimensions (matrices' size) that will allow a matrix representation of the group...

Comment: I guess, without being sure of it, that the $4 \times 4$ matrices deal with quaternion representation.

Comment: Has this document been of some help ?

Comment: Hi Jean, Thanks for that link, very interesting! I was aware of the golden ratio, but not aware of the specific operators to use come up with the matrices around a vector that would pass through one of the 5-folds.

Comment: A 72° rotation around axis $OV$ where $V$ is any vertex of the icosahedron doesn't look to leave invariant the icosahedron if I refer for example to animation https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/icosahedron.html ?